# Docker and electron-builder keep building for linux but I want Windows

Tags: docker, electron, quasar-framework

I am using Docker to build an Electron package (with Quasar) on my Mac. I need it to be built for Windows. I tried just building it directly with the quasar build command and configuring quasar.conf.js to build for windows, but apparently it's using wine, and wine can only build for win32, and I need it built for Windows 64-bit.  Thus I'm trying Docker, as I've read it may work.

Anyway, this is the code I'm using to start the Docker container. This is straight off the Docker website:

```
docker run --rm -ti \
 --env-file <(env | grep -iE 'DEBUG|NODE_|ELECTRON_|YARN_|NPM_|CI|CIRCLE|TRAVIS_TAG|TRAVIS|TRAVIS_REPO_|TRAVIS_BUILD_|TRAVIS_BRANCH|TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST_|APPVEYOR_|CSC_|GH_|GITHUB_|BT_|AWS_|STRIP|BUILD_') \
 --env ELECTRON_CACHE="/root/.cache/electron" \
 --env ELECTRON_BUILDER_CACHE="/root/.cache/electron-builder" \
 -v ${PWD}:/project \
 -v ${PWD##*/}-node-modules:/project/node_modules \
 -v ~/.cache/electron:/root/.cache/electron \
 -v ~/.cache/electron-builder:/root/.cache/electron-builder \
 electronuserland/builder:wine
```

Then I run the yarn commands:

```
yarn && yarn dist
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "pawtap3",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Paw Tap Description",
  "main": "./src/router/index.js",
  "productName": "Paw Tap 3",
  "author": "C. Heyman",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue ./",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,vue,scss,html,md,json}\" --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "test": "echo \"No test specified\" && exit 0",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.electron.pawtap",
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "dexie": "^3.2.2",
    "dexie-export-import": "^1.0.3",
    "downloadjs": "^1.4.7",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.25",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.7",
    "o": "^2.3.2",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "quasar": "^2.0.0",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.13.14",
    "@quasar/app": "^3.0.0",
    "electron": "^19.0.7",
    "electron-packager": "^15.2.0",
    "electron": "^16.0.7",
    "electron-builder": "^22.14.13",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 10 Chrome versions",
    "last 10 Firefox versions",
    "last 4 Edge versions",
    "last 7 Safari versions",
    "last 8 Android versions",
    "last 8 ChromeAndroid versions",
    "last 8 FirefoxAndroid versions",
    "last 10 iOS versions",
    "last 5 Opera versions"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 12.22.1",
    "npm": ">= 6.13.4",
    "yarn": ">= 1.21.1"
  }
}
```

It's building the files, but it insists on building a .snap file and an .AppImage file.  But I want Windows (nsis) or a Windows installer.  What am I doing wrong so that it's building Linux instead of Windows?

I have never used Docker before so it's a big learning curve.
Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this, but dont forget change your project directory `C:\PATH\YOUR-ELECTRON-APP\`:

```bash
docker run --rm -it -v C:\PATH\YOUR-ELECTRON-APP\:/project electronuserland/builder:wine /bin/bash -c "yarn && yarn dist -w"
```

Only windows:

```bash
yarn && yarn dist -w
```

windows and linux:

```bash
yarn && yarn dist -wl
```

macos, windows and linux:

```bash
yarn && yarn dist -mwl
```

docker command in windows change your proyect folder `C:\PATH\YOUR-ELECTRON-APP\`:

```bash
docker run --rm -it -v C:\PATH\YOUR-ELECTRON-APP\:/project electronuserland/builder:16-wine /bin/bash -c "yarn && yarn dist -mwl"
```

I use node 16 version in my project, so I need this docker image: `electronuserland/builder:16-wine`